# Modifying digits in multi-line continuous summary table? {gtsummary}

Tags: r, gtsummary

I'm trying to create a multi-line summary table for a continuous variable using gtsummary, with the appropriate digits displayed per row. I have outlined my the relevant arguments in the `statistics` and `digits` functions, however the corresponding number of digits are not displaying correctly in the output table. (e.g., kurtosis is reading as `0` when it should say `0.34`)

The challenge is that all of the statistics are attached to the same variable name (in this case, `qsec`), so I am not able to specify digit numbers per statistic to any certain variable. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!

```r
library(gtsummary)
library(psych)
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union


skew(mtcars$qsec)
#> [1] 0.3690453
kurtosi(mtcars$qsec)
#> [1] 0.3351142

mtcars %>%
  select(qsec) %>%
  tbl_summary(
    type = qsec ~ "continuous2",
    statistic = all_continuous() ~ c("{N_nonmiss}",
                                     "{mean} ({sd})", 
                                     "{median} ({p25}, {p75})", 
                                     "{min}, {max}",
                                     "{skew}",
                                     "{kurtosi}"),
    
    digits = all_continuous() ~  c(0,
                                   1,
                                   1,
                                   0,
                                   2,
                                   2),
   label = list(variable = ""),
    missing = "always",
    missing_text = "NA"
  ) %>% 
  add_stat_label(label = list(all_continuous() ~ c("N",
                                                   "Mean (SD)",
                                                   "Median (Q1, Q3)",
                                                   "Min, max",
                                                   "Skewness",
                                                   "Kurtosis")))
```

Table output can be found here: [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your `statistic` = declataration you have 10 statistics, therefore you would need as much as 10 digits declarations so as to control them all

```
#fragment
   digits = all_continuous() ~  c(0,
                                   1,1,
                                   1,1,1,
                                   0,0,
                                   2,
                                   2)
```